# SRID value=0 in geometry_columns for a view that explicitly uses ST_SetSRID

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

PostgreSQL 15.2, PostGIS 3.3.2

I create a view which has geometry column composed of raw coordinates. I explicitly set the SRID. However, in geometry_columns view the SRID value is 0 for that view. How else can I force the SRID value?

```
CREATE VIEW a_view AS (
...
st_setsrid(st_makeline(ARRAY[st_makepoint(x1,y1), st_makepoint(x2,y2), st_makepoint(x3,y3)]), 3301) AS geometry
...
```

(Other views that reference geometries from tables get their SRID derived correctly.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostGIS requires a column registration via the PostgreSQL *typemod* system for objects not explicitly defined by DDL; registration can be inferred for objects known to the system via e.g. table definition DDL, for newly created types like in your *View* definition this is not possible.

The *typemod* registration can be invoked by an explicit `CAST` (`::`) to the fully qualified `GEOMETRY|GEOGRAPHY(<GEOMETRY_TYPE>, <SRID>)` data types (i.e. specifically including the *`<GEOMETRY_TYPE>`* & *`<SRID>`* *typemods*):

```
CREATE VIEW a_view AS (
  ...
  ST_SetSRID(
    ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[ST_MakePoint(x1,y1), ST_MakePoint(x2,y2), ST_MakePoint(x3,y3)]),
    3301
  )::GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, 3301) AS geometry
  ...
```